# Get string between two words using C# regex

Tags: c#, regex

I want to get text between two strings. For this, I have tried the below code.

```
string q = "SELECT \"NORTHWIND\".\"CUSTOMER_DETAILS_NORTHWIND\".\"CUSTOMER_ID\" FROM \"NORTHWIND\".\"CUSTOMER_DETAILS_NORTHWIND\"";
        Regex regex = new Regex("SELECT(.*)FROM");
var result = regex.Match(q).Value;
```

**Output**: SELECT \"NORTHWIND\".\"CUSTOMER_DETAILS_NORTHWIND\".\"CUSTOMER_ID\" FROM

But I expected result without SELECT and FROM keyword.

**Expected Output:** \"NORTHWIND\".\"CUSTOMER_DETAILS_NORTHWIND\".\"CUSTOMER_ID\"

Can anyone suggest me how to achieve this?

Comment: Try lookbehind for SELECT and looahead for FROM keyword.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var match = Regex.Match(s, @"(?i)SELECT\s+(.+?)\s+FROM");
if (match.Success)  {
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: I suggest `(.+?)` - get as few letters as possible in case of `select 123 from select 456 from mytable`; another suggestion is using *case insensitive* regular expression option

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I added case-insensitive search.

Comment: imagine, that you have `"select myField from MyTable, (select otherField from other table) ..."` query, it seems that want `myField` match only, not `myField from MyTable, (select otherField` match; that's why it's reasonable to obtain as few letter as possible: `(.+?)`

Comment: It's easy to find out a *counter example* (*regular expression* is not a *parser*), say `select /*select 1 from dual*/ myField as "from", myOther from MyTable`; however, the *regular expression* does its work as it can, +1

Answer (score -1):

You can do it without `RegEx` too.

```
public static string GetBetweenTwoWords(string firstWord,string secondWord,string str){
    var firstWordIndex = str.IndexOf(firstWord) + firstWord.Length;
    var secondWordIndex = str.IndexOf(secondWord);
    return str.Substring(firstWordIndex,secondWordIndex - firstWordIndex);
}
```

Test:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string q = "SELECT \"NORTHWIND\".\"CUSTOMER_DETAILS_NORTHWIND\".\"CUSTOMER_ID\" FROM \"NORTHWIND\".\"CUSTOMER_DETAILS_NORTHWIND\"";
    Console.WriteLine(GetBetweenTwoWords("SELECT","FROM",q));

}
```

Output:

```
"NORTHWIND"."CUSTOMER_DETAILS_NORTHWIND"."CUSTOMER_ID"
```

Answer (score -2):

Here you go:

```
  "SELECT\s+\K\\".*(?=\sFROM)
```

no need for capture groups, just take the regex match
(you can also remove the "SELECT\s+    (it's just an extra verification)

Comment: This is not a valid .NET regex. You can see it yourself [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester).